# terraform how to breakup environment with modules

Tags: module, terraform, infrastructure

I am a bit confused with terraform modules. I get the idea of code reusability using modules. Any code you create in a directory is essentially a module. What I am struggling with is how modularized do you get? Should each module contain individual resource information like so:

```
/modules/security_groups/ssh/main.tf      <-- only has one aws_security_group resource
/modules/security_groups/http-80/main.tf  <-- only has one aws_security_group resource
/modules/security_groups/http-443/main.tf <-- only has one aws_security_group  resource
/modules/launch_configuration/main.tf     <-- only has one aws_launch_configuration resource 
/modules/auto_scaling_group/main.tf       <-- only has one auto_scaling_group resource
/modules/instances/main.tf                <-- only has one instance resource
....

/stage/vpc/main.tf
/stage/services/frontend-app/salon.tf   <-- source multiple /modules/... and vpc


/prod/vpc/main.tf
/prod/services/frontend-app/salon.tf    <-- source multiple /modules/... and vpc
```

Or should each module contain a combination of resource information. For example, take this directory structure.

```
/modules/salon-app/main.tf  <-- has more than one resource aws_security_group, auto_scaling_group, launch_configuration_group ...etc
....

/stage/vpc/main.tf
/stage/services/frontend-app/salon.tf  <-- source /modules/salon-app/.. only once


/prod/vpc/main.tf
/prod/services/frontend-app/salon.tf  <-- source /modules/salon-app/.. only once
```

Basically do you bundle aws resources into one big file or split them up into individual files per resources and then source them all separately?

Comment: I had the same question and I ended up combining the resources into a module (your last block of example). See my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611713/should-i-be-creating-simple-modules-or-modules-for-an-entire-app-stack

Comment: Thanks for that! Everything I been reading online, blogs and various examples of terraform code has been pointing to combining resources into one file as well. I am still confused how to then truly modularize it for different environments such that you only need to tweak a few parameters and not have to duplicate the code but I guess well see how it works out. Maybe I was trying to do too much modularization I dont know...

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I've thought about this issue is this.  For somethings you create  you're going to want to group the resources together, such as something like creating an ECS cluster.  Here's an example of how to do that:
https://github.com/charles-d-burton/tf_ecs_cluster

In that example it will create a cluster, setup autoscaling, forward notifications, all of that.  Then you configure your outputs to output the information that would be relevant to other resources.  In that example I output the cluster name and arn.  For my use case I save the state of that in S3 with a tool called terragrunt.  I then reference that state in other modules/resources.  Basically, the breakdown goes like this:
VPCs - module
Clusters - module
Load balancers - module
Applications - resources that reference those modules.

The thing to keep in mind when structuring your terraform is to remember that you want to limit the blast radius damage you can do in an erroneous run.  That's why it's better to modularize chunks of infrastructure and reference their remote state rather than have a holistic approach to running it.  By referencing the remote state you're essentially creating an API contract between  your components.  It also makes  your terraform runs much faster if they don't need to check and recheck every piece of infrastructure.  Runs will also fail faster if dependent resources haven't been created already as the data they need to reference won't be available.